# URL Validation using forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs

I know what need to be corrected in the testcases. I tried changing the testcases using fireevent.change to give input to elements, which by doing to all testcases all are passed. But I need an improvisation or correction to my code so that it works fine for original testcases. As you can see only null values is taken as the input for elements in testcases. We are receiving output as Invalid URL. Can someone help me out here?

Below is the react application UI.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtHPv.png)

Here is URL VALIDATOR FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT CODE

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
// import '../UrlValidator.css';
function UrlValidator(){
    const [domain,setDomain] = useState("");
    const [path,setPath] = useState("");
    const [method,setMethod] = useState("GET");
    const [body,setBody] = useState("");
    const [message,setMessage] = useState("");
    const [color,setColor] = useState('');
    const urlPatternValidation = (Domain) => {
        const regex = new RegExp('(https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})[/\\w .-]*/?');  
        if(!Domain.includes('com')){
          return false;
        }  
        return regex.test(Domain);
      };
    const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!urlPatternValidation(domain)){
            setMessage('Invalid URL!Please recheck your URL');
            setColor('red');
        }
        else if(body && path){
        // var temp = domain + '/'+ path.split(' ').join('/');
        // setMessage(temp);
        // setColor('#4EDD4D');
        // try{
        // var obj = JSON.parse(body);
        // var res = message + '?';
        // for(let key in obj){
        //     res= res+ key+'='+obj[key];
        // }
        try{
          var obj = JSON.parse(body);
          var temp = domain + '/'+ path.split(' ').join('/');
          setMessage(temp);
          setColor('#4EDD4D');
          var res = temp + '?';
          for(let key in obj){
              res= res+ key+'='+obj[key];
          }
        if(!(method==="POST" || method==='PUT')){
            setMessage(res);
            setColor('#4EDD4D');
        }
        }
        catch(Exception){
            setColor('red');
            if (method==="POST" || method==='PUT'){
                setMessage('Error in the body');
              }
            else{
            setMessage('Error in the Body of the Query Params');
            } 
        }
        }
        else if(path && body===""){
        if (method==="POST" || method==='PUT'){
            setColor('red');
            setMessage('Error in the Body');
        }
        else{
            setMessage(domain+ '/'+ path.split(' ').join('/'));
            setColor('#4EDD4D');
        }
        }
        else if(body===""){
        if (method==="POST" || method==='PUT'){
            setMessage('Error in the Body');
            setColor('red');
        }
        }
    }

    return (
    <form className='template' data-testid='submit' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className='message' data-testid='message' style={{backgroundColor:color}}>{message}</div>
      <label>Domain</label><br></br>
      <input type="text" data-testid='domain' placeholder='Enter the domain URL' onChange={e=>{setDomain(e.target.value)}}></input><br></br>
      <label>Path</label><br></br>
      <input type="text" data-testid='path' placeholder='Enter the path variables separated by comma' onChange={e=>{setPath(e.target.value)}}></input><br></br>
      <label>Method</label><br></br>
      <select title="method"  data-testid='method' onChange={e=>{setMethod(e.target.value)}}>
        <option id ="GET" value="GET">GET</option>
        <option id ="POST" value="POST">POST</option>
        <option id ="PUT" value="PUT">PUT</option>
        <option id="DELETE" value="DELETE">DELETE</option>
      </select><br></br>
      <label>Body</label><br></br>
      <textarea id="Body" data-testid='body' placeholder="Enter the Query Params as an Object" onChange={e=>{setBody(e.target.value)}}></textarea>
      <br></br>
      <input type='submit' value="Validate"></input> 
      <br></br>
    </form>
    );
}

export default UrlValidator;
```

and below are the testcases which are being tested using the above component code .

```
import UrlValidator from "./components/UrlValidator";
import { render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Test URL Validator', () => {

    test('testcase1', () => {
        render(<UrlValidator />);

        const inputDomain = screen.getByTestId('domain');
        const inputPath = screen.getByTestId('path');
        const inputMethod = screen.getByTestId('method');
        const inputBody = screen.getByTestId('body');

        const form = screen.getByTestId('submit');

        expect(inputDomain).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputPath).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputMethod).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputBody).toBeTruthy();

        
        fireEvent.submit(form, {
            target : [
                {value : 'www.google.com'},
                {value : 'search all'},
                {value : 'GET'},
                {value : ''},
                
            ]
        });

        const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
        expect(message.textContent).toBe('www.google.com/search/all');

    });

    test('testcase2', () => {
        render(<UrlValidator />);

        const inputDomain = screen.getByTestId('domain');
        const inputPath = screen.getByTestId('path');
        const inputMethod = screen.getByTestId('method');
        const inputBody = screen.getByTestId('body');

        const form = screen.getByTestId('submit');

        expect(inputDomain).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputPath).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputMethod).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputBody).toBeTruthy();

        
        fireEvent.submit(form, {
            target : [
                {value : 'www.google.com'},
                {value : 'search all'},
                {value : 'GET'},
                {value : '{\"Name\":\"Max\"}'},
                
            ]
        });

        const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
        expect(message.textContent).toBe('www.google.com/search/all?Name=Max');

    });

    test('testcase3', () => {
        render(<UrlValidator />);

        const form = screen.getByTestId('submit');
        const inputMethod = screen.getByTestId('method');

        fireEvent.change(inputMethod, {target : {value : 'POST'}})
        
        fireEvent.submit(form, {
            target : [
                {value : 'www.google.com'},
                {value : 'posts'},
                {value : 'POST'},
                {value : '{\"Name\":\"Max\"}'}
            ]
        });

        const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
        expect(message.textContent).toBe('www.google.com/posts');

    })


    test('testcase4', () => {
        render(<UrlValidator />);

        const inputDomain = screen.getByTestId('domain');
        const inputPath = screen.getByTestId('path');
        const inputMethod = screen.getByTestId('method');
        const body = screen.getByTestId('body');

        const form = screen.getByTestId('submit');
        
        fireEvent.change(inputDomain, {target : {value: 'www.google.com'}});
        fireEvent.change(inputPath, {target : {value: 'search all'}});
        fireEvent.change(inputMethod, {target : {value: 'POST'}});
        
        fireEvent.submit(form, {
            target : [
                {value : 'www.google.com'},
                {value : 'search all'},
                {value : 'POST'},
                {value : ''},
                
            ]
        });

        const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
        expect(message.textContent).toBe('Error in the Body');

    })

    test('testcase5', () => {
        render(<UrlValidator />);

        const form = screen.getByTestId('submit');
        const inputMethod = screen.getByTestId('method');

        fireEvent.change(inputMethod, {target : {value : 'DELETE'}})
        
        fireEvent.submit(form, {
            target : [
                {value : 'www.google.com'},
                {value : 'posts'},
                {value : 'DLETE'},
                {value : ''}
            ]
        });

        const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
        expect(message.textContent).toBe('www.google.com/posts');

    });

    test('testcase6', () => {
        render(<UrlValidator />);

        const inputDomain = screen.getByTestId('domain');
        const inputPath = screen.getByTestId('path');
        const inputMethod = screen.getByTestId('method');
        const inputBody = screen.getByTestId('body');

        const form = screen.getByTestId('submit');

        expect(inputDomain).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputPath).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputMethod).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputBody).toBeTruthy();

        
        fireEvent.submit(form, {
            target : [
                {value : 'www.google.com'},
                {value : 'search all'},
                {value : 'GET'},
                {value : '{\"Name\":\"Max\"'},
                
            ]
        });

        const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
        expect(message.textContent).toBe('Error in the Body of the Query Params');

    });

})
```

Only testcase 4 is passing and here is the proof to that

```
FAIL  src/App.test.js
  Test URL Validator
    × testcase1 (52 ms)
    × testcase2 (10 ms)
    × testcase3 (13 ms)
    √ testcase4 (14 ms)
    × testcase5 (8 ms)
    × testcase6 (12 ms)

  ● Test URL Validator › testcase1

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "www.google.com/search/all"
    Received: "Invalid URL!Please recheck your URL"

      33 |
      34 |         const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
    > 35 |         expect(message.textContent).toBe('www.google.com/search/all');
         |                                     ^
      36 |
      37 |     });
      38 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:35:37)

  ● Test URL Validator › testcase2

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "www.google.com/search/all?Name=Max"
    Received: "Invalid URL!Please recheck your URL"

      64 |
      65 |         const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
    > 66 |         expect(message.textContent).toBe('www.google.com/search/all?Name=Max');
         |                                     ^
      67 |
      68 |     });
      69 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:66:37)

  ● Test URL Validator › testcase3

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "www.google.com/posts"
    Received: "Invalid URL!Please recheck your URL"

      86 |
      87 |         const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
    > 88 |         expect(message.textContent).toBe('www.google.com/posts');
         |                                     ^
      89 |
      90 |     })
      91 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:88:37)

  ● Test URL Validator › testcase5

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "www.google.com/posts"
    Received: "Invalid URL!Please recheck your URL"

      138 |
      139 |         const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
    > 140 |         expect(message.textContent).toBe('www.google.com/posts');
          |                                     ^
      141 |
      142 |     });
      143 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:140:37)

  ● Test URL Validator › testcase6

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "Error in the Body of the Query Params"
    Received: "Invalid URL!Please recheck your URL"

      169 |
      170 |         const message = screen.getByTestId('message');
    > 171 |         expect(message.textContent).toBe('Error in the Body of the Query Params');
          |                                     ^
      172 |
      173 |     });
      174 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:171:37)
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific, _concise_ question. See ask.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is you are checking a  state value i.e `domain` befor it got update/not updated at all

```
 if(!urlPatternValidation(domain)){
            setMessage('Invalid URL!Please recheck your URL');
            setColor('red');
        }
```

In your tests you are not updating state values , instead submitting  the form

```
 const inputDomain = screen.getByTestId('domain');
        const inputPath = screen.getByTestId('path');
        const inputMethod = screen.getByTestId('method');
        const inputBody = screen.getByTestId('body');

        const form = screen.getByTestId('submit');

        expect(inputDomain).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputPath).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputMethod).toBeTruthy();
        expect(inputBody).toBeTruthy();

        
        fireEvent.submit(form, {
            target : [
                {value : 'www.google.com'},
                {value : 'search all'},
                {value : 'GET'},
                {value : ''},
                
            ]
        });
```

You can try like this

```
const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
const domain = formData.get("domain") //name of the element
//write your logic from here
```

Comment: I am currently a beginner still , as i have started only 1 week back .  But i took the domain as a state , so will the code work even after that if i substitute with your logic?

Comment: Code will work, the issue with test case there you are directly submitting the form without  updating state value, Try firing  ```onChange``` events for all the controlled inputs

Comment: i figured that out when i run the test interactively , but my trainee need the concise solution to it with out modifying the testcases

Comment: Okay then go with the solution I provided, where you can grab the every form element value.

Comment: So all i need to do is upon clicking on validate button , capture the event using handleSubmit and run the same logic as it is right?

Comment: Yes follow this code and get all the elements/input value ```const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
const domain = formData.get("domain")```, like this for every input by giving their name

Comment: Even after doing that only 1 testcase passes i.e testcase-4 , so any other idea